# Help me install a wlan smart switch - Problem with outlets

Tags: wiring

This is the fifth or sixth time I try to find help as nobody could help me (support of the switch didn't answer)

I currently purchased a smart switch and tried to install it but can't get it to work properly. (I think 
the device works perfectly, but I mess up the correct wiring)

Here's my problem:

I connect everything according to the instructions. The lightswitch works!
(The proper wiring Is described in the manual,
You have to connect the neutral wire, the current-carying wire and the light switch wire in the holes for N, L, and load respectively.

But my outlets (normal outlets, basically all outlets in my room) don't work anymore. The outlets only work if the
neutral wire is connected to the current-carrying one. So I tried to install the switch as before (everything according to the instructions as above, so that the switch works) AND additionally wire the neutral wire with the current-carrying one (parallel). Now the outlets work but the the switch doesnt.

Thanks already:)

that's how the problem looks like(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zcYH.jpg)

switch works, outlets dont (colors of wires not like in the books...all messed up)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7zhD.jpg)

Outlets work, switch doesnt(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb7sx.jpg)

The switch I am using: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07RJHVDH4/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_bjUWDb6T3AYWV

Comment: Providing the make and model of the switch is a good first step in helping us identify the problem.

Comment: "The outlets only work if the neutral wire is connected to the current-carrying one."  **Stop and shut off the breaker IMMEDIATELY**. Something is dangerously wrong.  The subject matter is off topic here but you need to seek assistance from an electrician in sorting out this wiring situation, even disregarding this new gadget.

Comment: Thanks! But the neutral wire has been connected with the current-carying one for like 10 years :/

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07RJHVDH4/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_bjUWDb6T3AYWV

Comment: Perhaps the wire I use isn't a neutral wire after all...but why does the switch work then?

Comment: Martin, please put all new information in the question body, not down here. We'll get you sorted out. There are a number of regulars who are electricians (and a few of us who play them on the internet).

Comment: What colors are these wires? Can we have photos of the setup?

Comment: Edited it! Although colors are arbitrary (no color codes :/)

Comment: "the neutral wire has been connected with the current-carying one for like 10 years" that's precisely the dangerous situation *or equally dangerous misunderstanding of the situation* that you need to sort out before you can even think about adding the smart switch.

Comment: Yup...I know that now...but i really don't know how to figure out. Especially that I dont actually think it's neutral

Comment: A lot of electricians use a single piece of romex (black and white wire in the US) to run from the switch to the light.  Therefore, what you think is a neutral is actually just a switch leg.

Comment: Thanks! So it actually isn't a neutral one...but how is it that the switch works with it? I mean...except that the outlet doesn't

Comment: Did you actually verify that any of the 'smart' features of the switch work? A plain wall switch does not require a neutral. I bet your switch works as a plain switch, but the computer inside doesn't work. (It's also possible that it's got clever tricks to work without neutral, but is better off with.) In any case, your "neutral" is absolutely not a neutral, and it would help if you could tell us what made you imagine that it might be! It's black, whereas neutrals are white; it has voltage on it when disconnected, whereas neutrals do not; it supplies power to outlets, which neutrals do not do!

Comment: Given that you don't know these things, it's very questionable whether you should be doing DIY electrical work like this. You need to consider the possibility that you could electrocute yourself, or miswire something and burn down your house.

Comment: True. I will probably read some articles, buy a multimeter and try to measure everything...probably have to install the neutral wire then

Comment: Is this even a listed switch ? I looked at the link everything is in German? But I did not see any listing info I did see ce on one of the photos , and the wire colors may indicate it would be ok in other parts of the world.

Comment: It has a ce sign on it...but I took your all advise and returned it...probably have to wire a neutral wire :/